# How to prevent saving data from causing deadlock in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous

i've a function which insert in the database async. , that function is call at background transfer status changed and sometime it causing deadlock

```
    await vm.InsertVerseDownloadProgress_Bulk(tracks.Cast<QuranVerseTrack>().ToList()).ConfigureAwait(true);

    await vm.InsertVerseDownloadProgress_Bulk(tracks.Cast<QuranVerseTrack>().ToList()).ConfigureAwait(false);

    await vm.InsertVerseDownloadProgress_Bulk(tracks.Cast<QuranVerseTrack>().ToList()).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

i'm not sure which one to use

Answer (score 0):

ConfigureAwait(true) is the default and causes your Task to marshal back to the thread it was started at.

The deadlock is mostly caused by waiting on the result somewhere in the UI tread (wait, not await; by calling task.wait or task.result).

Your question cannot be answered without further context.

Comment: so if i use it just like "vm.InsertVerseDownloadProgress_Bulk(tracks.Cast<QuranVerseTrack>().ToList())" it shouldn't cause a problem

Comment: "It Depends". :)
If you want to Change something in the UI after you awaited that code, you are fine.
If you don't, you can use ConfigureAwait to have prevent useless ThreadMarshalling.

All I can say at this Point is, that this configure await is not the only Thing relevant to your propblem and you need to provide more context.